# PL/SQL: How to get ORA-Code in an exception?

Tags: plsql

I'm calling in a PL/SQL-Procedure another procedure. Now i'll put a begin-exception-block around this call.

If this sub-procedure fails and throws an exception, i get in the exception-block after the call. But how can I now know which ORA-Code the exception has? Is there any keyword existing for that?

Thx for help

Flo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [SQLCODE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqlcode_function.htm) and [SQLERRM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqlerrm_function.htm)